# I need a TSE (The Semware Editor) replacement for Windows / Linux / OS X / Solaris (one to edit them all)

Tags: editing

My text and programmers editor of choice, when working on a windows box is TSE (The Semware Editor).  It is small, it is fast, it is configurabel, and since I've used it (and it's predecessor QEdit) for over twenty years, my fingers can do the editing on autopilot, while the brain is busy with syntax and design.

Do you know of a similar editor preferably one that runs on Windows, Linux and OS X (and Solaris ..)

I've tried to use VIM (I know how to use VI even longer thant TSE) but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: I am now using Sublime Text (licensed)  with default key bindings. It works where I need it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you'll find a clone of The Semware Editor, and especially not on all three operating systems.

Your best bet would be to find a customizable text editor available on the three operating systems, and customize it to emulate The Semware Editor as closely as possible. This would probably be a very hard and long job. I would really advise you to find and get used to a new text editor.

One candidate would be [XEmacs](http://www.xemacs.org/) (although it does require Cygwin under Windows):

> XEmacs is a highly customizable open
>   source text editor and application
>   development system. It is protected
>   under the GNU Public License and
>   related to other versions of Emacs, in
>   particular GNU Emacs. Its emphasis is
>   on modern graphical user interface
>   support and an open software
>   development model, similar to Linux.
>   XEmacs has an active development
>   community numbering in the hundreds,
>   and runs on Windows 95 and NT, Linux
>   and nearly every other version of Unix
>   in existence. Support for XEmacs has
>   been supplied by Sun Microsystems,
>   University of Illinois, Lucid,
>   ETL/Electrotechnical Laboratory,
>   Amdahl Corporation, BeOpen, and
>   others, as well as the unpaid time of
>   a great number of individual
>   developers.

Answer (score 0):

Me too, near as I can tell The Semware Editor was last updated some 15 years ago. However, it still works great for me. And of course I've done too, too many macros. Doing even the ones that I still use frequently in a new and unfamiliar editor would be really nice to avoid.

That said I do find that for python programs I am doing a lot more work in PyCharm these days.

By the way I just checked the Semware Editor is still for sale on the Semware web site.

Comment: Does Semware Editor run on all three operating systems mentioned? If not, recommending it can not be considered as a response to the question.